# Detecting special characters PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to check whether a string contains any special chars so I know what to do with it afterwards in my script.

Heres what I have:

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Z0-9_@£\$¥èéùìòÇØø\+%&\!"#'\(\)\*,\-\.ÅåÆæß¤:;<=>?¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà€ΓΔΘΛΞΠΣΦΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψωςέάόίώύήϊϋΐΰΆΈΊΉΌΎΏXΥΡΟΝΜΚΗΖΕΙΤΑΧΒ\^\{\}\\\[~\]\|\/ \n\r]/',$message)) {}
```

However I get the following error `syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR`.

Comment: Look at that code highlighting.

Comment: Code highlight shows you where is your error.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot some escapes:

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Z0-9_@£\$¥èéùìòÇØø\+%&\!"#'\(\)\*,
               ^-start string                  ^---end string
```

Since that's a `'`-quoted string for the pattern as a whole, all `'` inside the pattern **MUST** be escaped.

Comment: So this then: `\'/[^A-Z0-9_@£\$¥èéùìòÇØø\+%&\!"#\'\(\)\*,` ?

Comment: I tried escaping that, and it doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare all alphanumeric characters against the string to check if there is any special character:

```
$temp = '$tack0verflow_';

if(strlen($temp) == strlen(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $temp))){
    // No special characters
} else {
    // Has special characters
}
```